# Pre-images of closed sets are open

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two topological spaces and let $f$ be such a map that $f^{-1}(A)$ is open in $X$ for any closed $A$. Note that if $X\stackrel{f}{\longrightarrow}Y\stackrel{g}\longrightarrow  Z$ are two such maps, then $g\circ f$ is continuous. Perhaps, it is a trivial task - but is there an example of such surjective map from $\Bbb R$ to $\Bbb R$?

Comment: I can't see why you think $\,g\circ f\,$ is cont.: we know that for any closed $\,A\subset Z\;$, then $\;g^{-1}(A)\subset Y\,$ is open, but we don't know whether $\,f^{-1}\left(g^{-1}(A)\right)=(g\circ f)^{-1}(A)\subset X\,$ is *closed* ...

Comment: Such a map does not exist. For any $x\in \mathbb R$, the set $O_x=f^{-1}(\{ x\})$ should be open end nonempty; but these sets are pairwise disjoint.

Comment: @DonAntonio $g^{-1}(A)$ is open in $Y$, so $Y - g^{-1}(A)$ is closed, hence $$ X - (g\circ f)^{-1}(A) = f^{-1}(Y-g^{-1}(A))$$ is open.

Comment: Yes @martini...so?

Comment: @martini If the preimages of clsed sets are always open, then the preimages of open sets are always closed. $f^{-1}(A^c)=f^{-1}(A)^c$.

Comment: @DonAntonio: don't we get that the pre-image of any open set is closed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $f\colon \mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ have the given property.
Since points are closed, we get pairwise disjoint open sets $f^{-1}(x)$. If $x$ is in the image of $f$, then $f^{-1}(x)$ contains some open interval and hence a rational number. We conclude that $f^{-1}(x)\ne\emptyset$ only for countably many $x$, i.e. $f$ is not surjective.

Comment: +1 I think this is a great answer. Clearly, you're a prolific contributor to math stackexchange as well. I'd just like to take this opportunity to thank you for your excellent contributions here!

Answer (score 5):

***Theorem 1***

Let $f:X\to Y$ be such a map of topological spaces with $X$ connected and $Y$ a $T_1$-space. Then $f$ is constant.

**Proof**

The collection of sets $f^{-1}(\{y\})$ for $y\in Y$ constitutes a non-trivial separation of $X$ if $f$ is not constant.

**Q.E.D.**

***Theorem 2*** (based on Hagen von Eitzen's answer)

Let $f:X\to Y$ be such a map of topological spaces with $X$ separable and $Y$ an uncountable $T_1$-space. Then $f$ is not surjective.

**Proof**

See Haigen von Eitzen's excellent answer and try to generalize it to a proof!

**Q.E.D.**

I hope this helps!